# Vim spell checking within code

Tags: vim, spell-checking, neovim

I know how to use Vim's built in spell checking, but I was wondering if there was anything similar to this [VS Code plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker)

I find it's immensely helpful since it'll show spelling issues within variable names and takes camel/snake case into account.

Answer (score 0):

The one I use - Code Spell Checker by Street Side Software -
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker

Comment: isn't this for vs code ? I mean do they have a plugin for neo vim ?